# How to Preload and Select only records that match the condition specified in the Preload clause

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I have been beating my head against this for a while now, but haven't found a reliable solution yet.

In GORM, if I have two tables

```golang
type Person struct {
    Accounts []Account // hasMany relationship. Single person has many accounts
}

type Account struct {
    Name     string
    PersonID string
}
```

How do I retrieve a tag that has a matching name?

I am expecting to retrieve a matching Person with given account name.

the closest I have gotten to is with

```golang
// DB is a gorm.DB struct
DB.Preload("Accounts", "name = ?", "foo").Find(&personList)

However, this does conditional preloading (duh) and not search on the joined table for a matching account name.
```

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins